# Как убрать повторения имени?

Tags: yii2, yii

Есть список ингредиентов, сверху полей есть наименование блюда к которому относиться ингредиент, скажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так что бы наименование блюда не повторялось, а было выведено только один раз!?

Есть так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А сделать нужно так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код во view:

```
<?php foreach ($values as $index => $value): ?>
    <div class="disabled"><?=$value->valuesAttribute->name?></div>
    <?=$form->field($value, "[$index]name")->label(false);?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо формировать запрос с группировкой по блюду или собирать два отдельных массива (названия блюд и ингредиенты). Либо сразу собрать правильный массив.

```
$products = ['name' => ['milk', 'patato']];
```

Более эффективно будет в ключе указывать не название блюда, а его id. Тогда можно сформировать массив моделей с названием блюд и работать уже с ним. Для более подробного ответа надо посмотреть на модели и контроллер.